# I want to know the post count by authors of my wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know how many posts posted by a particular author. For example. There are 10 authors and each of them posts , now i want to know the count of posts done by the author.

Blog: viyugam.com

Answer (score 0):

Post count is returned by this function for user whose id is passed to it .  [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts) can help

Comment: What i need here is i am admin i want to know how many posts posted by a particular author?

Comment: <?php echo 'Posts made: ' . get_usernumposts(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Use single user post

```
count_user_posts( $userid );
```

or

pass the user_id's in array to this function, to get the post count of users

```
count_many_users_posts($user_ids_array);
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts